# UnityWebRequest doesn't work in Oculus Go

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculusgo, unitywebrequest

I have a question about UnityWebRequest when using in Oculus Go. UnityWebRequest work well in UnityEditor. However, UnityWebRequest doesn't work in Oculus Go... It seems just no connect to http url because there is no log in putty.

```
IEnumerator GetArt()
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("galleryidx", 1);
        Debug.Log("get art");
        string Url = "http://[awsIPaddress]/vr/enterGallery";

        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post(Url, form);
        request.chunkedTransfer = false;
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.isNetworkError)
        {
            //show message "no internet "
            Debug.Log("no internet");
        }
        else
        {
            if (request.isDone)
            {
                Debug.Log("getting image");
                Debug.Log(request.downloadHandler.text);
                //using JsonHelper to get json data
                allPosts = JsonHelper.getJsonArray<Post>(request.downloadHandler.text);
                StartCoroutine(GetArtsImages());
            }
        }
    }
```

Our team really wants to fix this problem, but there is no error message so we doesn't know what causes this problem. Is there any ideas to How can I fix it? We are using unity 2018.4.15f1.

We also read similar post(https://forum.unity.com/threads/unitywebrequest-not-working-for-oculus-quest.830199/ ) and modified AndroidManifest...but still same as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

we just solved.
unity project android manifest file didn't include
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`. We also change build system as Internal in build setting.